# Angular: getting error when building with --prod flag

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have Angular 2 app, I have 2 diff. behavior when running app depend on --prod flag when building app:

1. **ng build** // WORKS
2. **ng build --prod** // ERROR IN RUNTIME

So when building with --prod I got:

**Uncaught Error: Cannot resolve all parameters for 'z'(?, ?, ?). Make sure that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type annotations and that 'z' is decorated with Injectable.**

Thanks for any help

Comment: Have you done what the error message tells you to do? Why do you still use Angular 2, instead of the latest Angular 5?

Comment: It's actually Angular 5, I miswrite Angular 2, thanks for notising

Comment: Without code, we can't help.

Answer (score 1):

--prod mode is minifying your code. Thus injection will not work anymore unless you mark the classes, where you use dependency injection accordingly. (Which is what the error message tries to tell you)

You will have to mark all classes accordingly to the docs in order to make your app run in minification mode. Furthermore i strongly recommend updating to Angular 5. I think the behavior and error messages have improved in that regard.

Comment: Can you please give me hint, what to change in the code? I have all services with @Injectable(), and as I understand correctly your answer, I have to add also "SOMETHING" into component where the services are injected.

Comment: Yes, the @Injectable is the decorator needed. You are missing it somehwhere in your code. You will have to check your code in order to find the right spot, unfortunately. also you have to make sure that "emitDecoratorMetadata" is set to true in you tsconfig, but since it's the default, i assume the problem is not that one